# How to Solve select option error null reference exception after submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on a project that involved the use of the select option in ASP.Net Core 7.0, I encountered some difficulties. Specifically, I faced errors related to a null reference exception in my dropdown. However, I observed that after submitting the data, it is installed into the SQL database, upon returning after submission, a null reference exception error is displayed. These errors have made the development process quite challenging, and I'm hoping to find a solution soon. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Error**

[image]

**Action**

```
public IActionResult Apply()
{

    ViewBag.Courselist = new SelectList(GetAllAccountIDList(), "Id", 
    "CourseName");
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Apply(PurchasedFormViewModel purchasedFormVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    try
    {
        var transaction = new StudentBiodataViewModels
        {
            CourseId = purchasedFormVM.CourseId,
            SurName = purchasedFormVM.SurName,
            OtherName = purchasedFormVM.OtherName,
            PhoneNumber = purchasedFormVM.PhoneNumber,
            Email = purchasedFormVM.Email,
        };
        _context.StudentBiodata.Add(transaction);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ViewBag.Message = ex.Message + " Error occur while inserting records.";
    }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Models**

```
 public class ApplyFormViewModel
 { 
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Course Apply")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Course Apply is Required")]
     public int CourseId { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "SurName")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "SurName is Required")]
     public string SurName { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Other Name")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Other Name is Required")]
     public string OtherName { get; set; } 
     [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is Required")]
     ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid.")]
     public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } 
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
     public string Email { get; set; }
     
 }
```

**View**

```
<select id="fundcode" asp-for="CourseId" class="form-control">
    <option value="">--Please select--</option>
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Courselist )
    {
        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: You have a controller and need an exception handler.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Answer (score -1):

You are returning from the POST to the same view called in the GET handler, but without setting the *ViewBag.CourseList*. Of course when the page is rendered that variable is NULL and you get the exception.

I think you need to add the same code used in the GET just before returning to the View inside the Post handler

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Apply(PurchasedFormViewModel purchasedFormVM)
{
    .....
    ViewBag.Courselist = new SelectList(GetAllAccountIDList(), "Id", "CourseName");
    return View();
}
```